# How to get a farm property with CSOM?

Tags: client-object-model

In my farm solution I have created a farm feature to render additional links in the chrome control, from the FARM object property bag.

Basically I took this example:
http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/02/10/addremove-links-in-top-suitebar-skydrivesitesnewsfeed-in-sharepoint-2013/

And then I changed the code to read from the property bag in 4 property bags
CustomLink1, CustomLinkName1, CustomLink2, CustomLinkName2

I want to develop an APP and to have the same look and feel(chrome control), from the host web. This is well explained here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d60f409a-b292-4c06-8128-88629091b753

But I want to read the additional links I built initialy in my farm solution, so I need to read property bag values from the farm, not the spweb object like here:

http://sureshpydi.blogspot.be/2013/05/set-and-get-property-bag-values-in.html

How could I read those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite certain that you can never get high enough privileges for that in an app. Even if you possibly could, it would mean that your app would need very high permissions for a very simple and small task.

Can't you save the properties in an easier to access place, like a list on one or all Site collections root web, and then grab it by search?

Or, if you are allowed, build a custom webservice that retrieves the values from the farm property bag and then call that webservice method from your app.

Comment: I like the webservice option!